# Did the marketing of Terminator 2 actually spoil the movie?

Tags: terminator-series, reception, marketing, terminator-2-judgment-day

I recently read this [article](http://thedissolve.com/features/movie-of-the-week/670-terminator-2-and-the-worlds-biggest-spoiler/) which points out the build-up James Cameron did intentionally to mislead who the assassin robot was in [*Terminator 2: Judgement Day*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103064/) and how the marketing campaign immediately killed any suspense. It's a really good break down of the scenes. I remember originally watching the movie that I kept expecting the T-800 to become the bad guy for some reason but have never really thought about why.

Nowadays the word *spoiler* is used to describe a pre-explaining of plot details in a story that are meant to be a surprise. So revealing the T-800 as the good guy this time definitely could be considered a spoiler but it also can be described as the basic [logline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_line) of the movie. *The Terminator comes back in time again this time to save John Connor from another Terminator.* With that taken into consideration, did the marketing for T2 actually spoil the movie? Even the article pointed out that it "got butts in seats".

Now without getting into a too opinionated discussion if the movie would have been better with or without the surprise, I'd be interested if there was anything ever said by James Cameron as to whether marketing ruined the suspense he was trying to build? Was this marketing strategy and this "spoiling" of the surprise always intended as part of the movie's overall impression or did it simply slip from the filmmakers' hands?

Comment: How would you measure this? By audience reaction? Personally, I'd edit your title as this sounds very subjective (i.e. asking for opinions) as it stands.

Comment: @AndrewMartin What's wrong with asking for opinions? I don't mean for it to be "opinion-based" but aren't all reviews and critiques of cinema opinion-based? This is a probably a question that should go to Meta but I hope it's not needed for this question. The article does a good job of using scenes from the movie to support it's theory. This is what I expect from a good answer to this question. Something ringing closer to an analysis than just an opinion. Asking for a quote from James Cameron if possible, I think clarifies that sources should be used to support any stated opinion.

Comment: I don't know how any answer could objectively address the question. If an answer begins "I think it spoiled the movie" it's obviously subjective. You could look at the amount of money the movie made, but what would you compare it to? The "unspoiled" movie was never released, so any financial information is subjective too. Even a quote from the director wouldn't answer that question, as it would simply be his opinion on the issue. Similarly, in response to your last question, how could "suspense" of a movie be accurately measured? I just think this question is far too subjective.

Comment: I think that it's pretty clear the OP is asking about from the Directors point of view. Did marketing ruin (spoil) Cameron's vision for the story he was telling (the movie)?

Comment: It is in essence a subjective question but I do think this one is definable and not open for debate but honest yes/no answers. To clarify because I don't want this question redirected, I am not just asking from the Directors point of view but I do feel his view would make a strong statement, I want an overall observation in retrospect of an event. I'm not asking if marketing took the wrong direction as that would be opinion only. It's not a simple question but the answer should not be completely opinion based but use logical statements from facts to support it's answer.

Comment: I still don't understand *how* this can be answered without being subjected. You say you want an overall observation in retrospect of an event - but what sort of observation? How could this question be answered objectively? Do you want a comparison of overall revenue compared to expected revenue? Do you want an article showing that a mass survey showed people were disappointed with the amount of suspense in the film, compared to what they expected? What would or could the director say to answer this *without* being subjective? I think we just have to agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: @BenPlont: The problem with those sorts of questions is that they lie open for ever unless the director happened to mention it in an interview - as otherwise any other opinion is pure speculation.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Alright how about I try to answer my own question and then you judge that as to whether or not it is too subjective.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Well, if there is no interview, then it seems the question would have to stay unanswered, so what? When concentrating on the viewpoint of the director, this question isn't really any opinion-based or unanswerable.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I remain unconvinced I'm afraid and have voted to close. I'm curious to see what answered are provided though.

Comment: @AndrewMartin See that's the problem though if the question is closed or even shows possibility of closing then there is much less chance of it receiving answers. I do plan to post a meta question about this subject.

Comment: Note to all: Meta discussion open on the closure of this question here: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/are-we-closing-to-soon

Comment: I tired to make it less opinion-based. Feel free to vote for reopening (my vote has already been used unfortunately).

Comment: I saw this when I first saw the movie in the theater. The way the first few scenes play out, it's obvious that Cameron is purposefully mimicking the first movie to try and lead the audience to believe that Patrick is playing the good guy and Schwarzenegger is again playing the baddie. Of course, marketing the film this way would be silly. You wouldn't be able to show cool clips from most of the movie, and it would look like a simple rehash of the first film.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson In my opinion, you did a great job extracting the core objective question here. Maybe we'll even get a definitive answer if Cameron does some interviews for publicity when T2 is re-released in 3D. (Yeah, yeah, wishful thinking on multiple fronts, but I feel fairly hopeful that this T2 re-release will in fact materialize.)

Comment: I laughed when I saw this question, as the spoiler of T2 in marketing pales in comparison to the spoiler of Terminator Genisys through its trailers which ruined large parts of the film. You would have thought that the Terminator franchise would have learned its lesson.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [jamescamerononline.com](http://www.jamescamerononline.com/T2Complexity.htm), "We've got a story worked out but it hasn't gone beyond the talk stage" - James Cameron on Terminator 2 in English Magazine 1985

William Wisher (The Making of T2, 1991):

> Jim pulled out this old yellow sheet of paper from a notebook and handed it to me without saying anything. there was one sentence scribbled on the dog eared page. It read: Young John Connor and the terminator that comes back to befriend him.

This shows that Cameron's original logline spoils the movie right there.

However, the article that OP (that's me) linked doesn't pull this "the marketing spoiled the idea of who's the bad terminator" out of nowhere. It directly states on jamescamerononline.com that:

> The movie is designed in such way that the audience doesn't know which of the time travelers is the good guy. The way the movie is shot and the story and angles constructed is to make them think that T-800 is the antagonist and T-1000 a human character. T-1000 is never shown to kill the cop or copy his clothes and seems very genuine when talking to John Connor's foster parents, while the T-800 is shown to go through the bar like a tank, crushing hands, breaking arms and seriously injuring people.

So did James Cameron spoil his own script that he wrote? He had complete control of the movie in almost all aspects. It seems strange that marketing got away from him. I haven't found a direct quote referencing this, but there is this quote from the same website:

> James Cameron (Globalnet): On T2, I wondered if I could get the audience to an emotional place where they would cry for the Terminator. That was my goal: Could I take world's coldest motherfucker and turn you around in a two-hour time period to where you actually felt sorry for him? Forget about all the hoo-ha with the liquid metal guy: that was fun, but getting the audience to cry for the Terminator was the big cinematic challenge. That's the reason I made the movie.

Yes, there was an intentional story development of suspense as to who the evil terminator was supposed to be. Marketing definitely blew a hole in this by stating point blank who was good and who was bad. However, it did not spoil anything. The suspense is meant for the story itself, and even knowing what the marketing of the movie was before watching, there are two things that would keep the suspense going despite knowing who is good and who is bad. One, marketing is wrong a lot and sometimes misleading on purpose. Two, the T-800 is so ruthless, it seems like it is still the bad one even after the reveal. It's not until it saves Sarah Connor that safety is guaranteed with this machine. Plus, one more thing from the characters perspective of John and Sarah Connor: the T-800 is the bad guy. That is from whose perspective we watch the movie.

So no, it wasn't spoiled, and yes, most likely Cameron was onboard for this marketing as it didn't change the storyline. His real intention and the payoff for him were to make the audience care about the T-800 as it sacrificed itself.

Comment: On a side note, never be put off answering your question regardless of how quickly you post your answer. Answering your own question isn't just allowed, it's encouraged.

Comment: *"James Cameron (Globalnet): On T2, I wondered if I could get the audience to an emotional place where they would cry for the Terminator. That was my goal: Could I take world's coldest motherfucker and turn you around in a two-hour time period to where you actually felt sorry for him? [...] That's the reason I made the movie""* - And how on earth do you conclude from this that *"there was an intentional story development of suspense as to who the evil terminator was supposed to be. Marketing definitely blew a hole in this"*?

Comment: And of course in addition to what *Andrew* said, in the same way never feel obliged to answer your own question *only* to stop it from closing (how on earth can an *answer* prevent a question from getting closed anyway?). So one could say you did the right thing for the wrong reason. ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I didn't conclude that from that statement. I came to the conclusion that it didn't matter to the director if it was leaked or known which Terminator was the bad guy. What mattered to him was by the end of the story you cared for the T-800. And as far as answering my own question in the comments Andrew Martin stated "I still don't understand how this can be answered without being subjected." I felt I had to provide an example since it couldn't be comprehended.

Comment: @KevinHowell *"I didn't conclude that from that statement. I came to the conclusion that it didn't matter to the director if it was leaked or known which Terminator was the bad guy. What mattered to him was by the end of the story you cared for the T-800."* - Indeed, that is also what I concluded. But the in the next sentence you suddenly write *"So yes there was an intentional story development of suspense as to who the evil terminator was supposed to be. Marketing definitely blew a hole in this"* - Which as you say, does *not* really follow from what *Cameron* said.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson No it doesn't follow what Cameron himself said in that quote but it does follow what the website said about the writing intentionally making it unclear who the bad guy was at first. I had to make an assumption that even though it wasn't a direct quote that it was still correct. So the paragraph I wrote was a summing up of the information from the two paragraphs above it.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson No I found an article that sparked an interest on a subject. I asked a question that I thought would be good for this site and community in general. I then felt I had to give an example on how the question could be answered without being completely opinion. In doing that I ran across the site that probably inspired the article since it pretty much copied part of jamescamerononline and just expounded on the scenes. The article made the statement that the marketing spoiled the movie the source never did. I don't agree with the article. I was wondering if anything backed it up.

Comment: Personal experience: I can't say whether the marketing spoiled the movie, but I saw the first two Terminator movies years after they came out, and I knew almost nothing about them.  The reveal works.  I was definitely surprised by the confrontation scene in the mall, when the T-1000 was revealed to be the bad guy.  Incidentally, the current IMDB blurb for the movie spoils it too: "A cyborg, identical to the one who failed to kill Sarah Connor, must now protect her ten year old son, John Connor, from a more advanced and powerful cyborg."

Comment: The reveal is handled very well in a movie, but one of the central aspects of popular cinema is to create suspense around things the audience really knows. For instance we know John Connor won't be killed, but there are lots of exciting scenes where he's put at risk. (Just as James Bond, Ethan Hunt, etc, go through lots of dangerous situations.)

Answer (score 4):

- *Terminator 2* grossed $204,843,345 in its domestic market and $315,000,000 in foreign markets. (source: [BoxOfficeMojo](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=terminator2.htm)).
- *Terminator 2* is widely regarded as one of the best sci-fi films of all time (source: my knowledge of sci-fi films and fans).

With these two facts in mind, I think it's safe to conclude that **nothing spoiled the movie**. To the contrary, the movie was a massive success.

Of course, if you had seen a preview that revealed Arnold's character to be a good guy, you would not be surprised by that revelation while you are watching the movie. And I would tend to agree that the movie would have been even cooler if that surprise had not been revealed in a preview. But then I wonder if reviews and other word-of-mouth would have ruined the surprise for most people anyway -- in other words, maybe the marketing strategy recognized that the twist was too big to stay a surprise.

Answer (score 4):

James Cameron's original intention was to save the reveal (that the original Terminator is now a goodie) for the film. The studio's marketing team apparently spoke to him ***while the film was still in development*** and convinced him that the 'reveal' would need to occur in the trailers and pre-marketing for the film rather than in the film itself.

> The original intention was the mislead the audience into believing that Terminator is once again the killer and that T-1000 - intentionally Reese-like in many respects - is a human protector, culminating in the revelation in the mall service corridor that the mysterious 'cop' is a terminator assassin and that Terminator is the good guy. It was thus important to subtly show that Terminator does not kill anybody without tipping the hand; by the same token, T-1000 had to be shown doing nothing extraordinary that would give him away as
> being a liquid metal terminator. In the final analysis, **it was determined that the existence of two terminators and Terminator's status as protector would be revealed as marketing points in the theatrical trailers and advertising campaign prior to the film's release; thus, there was less incentive to play the "bait and switch" idea out.** In its place, a slight transposition of action sequencing in this scene - Terminator shields John first, then blows T-1000 away - draws out the revelation of T-1000's pseudomorphic capabilities and portrays Terminator's protector role in action.
>
> <sub><sup>[Terminator 2: Judgment Day: The Book Of The Film - An Illustrated Screenplay](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day:_The_Book_Of_The_Film_-_An_Illustrated_Screenplay)</sup></sub>